# Salesforce1 app still giving error after latest release

Tags: salesforce1-app

There are users in our org still receiving an error(infinite loop) while accessing the Salesforce1 application even after the latest update.  The only way I can get them into the app without an error is to turn off the calendar access for Salesforce on their IOS devices.  Tried different iPad models and tried deselecting all the calendars(work, personal) in the calendar but same results.  Our org is running Outlook 365 and not all of the users are experiencing the issue but I am not sure what version of the Salesforce1 they are running either.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
​M

Comment: This sounds like one where you need to get a log from one of your user's devices and file a case with Salesforce and have them look at it. There are just far too many possibilities with too little information for us to give you much, if any guidance.

Comment: I have a Case open but I was hoping someone else in the Community was experiencing the same issue and had an idea of what was the root cause.  The error message loops so I cannot expand the error log view and typing into the error message box is hit or miss since the error is continuously looping.

Comment: Having same issue with IPhone 6S. Very aggravating

Comment: Salesforce is going to issue a patch but not expected until the Winter 17 release which is planned for mid OCtober.  Turn off Salesforce's access to your calendar on your device and this should resolve your issue until the new release....

Comment: and vote here:https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jl36QAA